# How to watch user browsing activity from a background service?

Tags: android, events

I'm trying to build an android app that can access the user's browsing activity.
Basically, if a page is loaded, my app should get notified.

Please don't say it is impossible. I actually saw an app do that (and even close a tab).

I've searched the internet, asked chatgpt and mistral but no one seems to know how they did it.